# .NET Core does not show user claims in middleware when authenticating with Azure AD

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-identity

I have a multi-tenant .NET Core web app where the current user's tenant is resolved via middleware. In particular, tenants are resolved with a library called [SaasKit.Multitenancy](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit).

To use this library, you put this line in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // (omitted for brevity)

    // The 'Tenant' type is what you resolve to, using 'ApplicationTenantResolver'
    services.AddMultitenancy<Tenant, ApplicationTenantResolver>();

    // ...
}
```

And you put this line in `Configure()` to add it to the middleware pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMultitenancy<Tenant>(); //this line
    app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

    // ...
}
```

This causes the following method in the middleware to be executed, which resolves the current user's tenant:

```
public async Task<TenantContext<Tenant>> ResolveAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    //whatever you need to do to figure out the tenant goes here.
}
```

This allows the result of this method (whichever tenant is resolved) to be injected into any class you want, like so:

```
private readonly Tenant _tenant;

public HomeController(Tenant tenant)
{
   _tenant = tenant;
}
```

Up until now, we have been authenticating users with the .NET Identity platform, storing user data in our app's database. However, a new tenant of ours wants to be able to authenticate their users via SSO.

I have figured out most of the SSO stuff--I am using Azure AD to sign in users, and [my organization's Azure AD tenant will be able to federate with their Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation). In short, this code in `ConfigureServices` adds the Identity and AzureAD authentication:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // rest of the code is omitted for brevity 

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config =>
    {
        config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => _configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)).AddCookie();

    // policy gets user past [Authorize] if they are signed in with Identity OR Azure AD
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                 AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                 IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme
               ).RequireAuthenticatedUser()
               .Build();
           options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

}
```

When using Identity, I have been able to resolve the users's tenant with the UserManager, like so:

```
public async Task<TenantContext<Tenant>> ResolveAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    TenantContext<Tenant> tenantContext = new TenantContext<Tenant>(new ApplicationTenant());
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.Users
                              .Include(x => x.Tenant)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == email);
        if (user?.Tenant != null)
        {
            tenantContext = new TenantContext<Tenant>(user.Tenant);
            _logger.LogDebug("The current tenant is " + user.Tenant.Name);
            return await Task.FromResult(tenantContext);
        }
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(tenantContext);
}
```

My plan was to modify this code so grabbed the current User's claims, which can be used to infer which tenant the user belongs to. **However, when authenticating a user via Azure AD, `HttpContext.User` is always empty in the middleware, despite the user being signed in. It's not null, but `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false and `HttpContext.User.Claims` is empty. I only see the value of `HttpContext.User` populated once routing is complete and the code has reached a Controller.**

I have tried reorganizing the middleware in pretty much every feasible way to no avail. What's confusing to me is that `HttpContext.User` is populated in the tenant resolver when the user is authenticated with Identity. With this in mind, I'm not sure how I can access the user's claims in the middleware when authenticating via Azure AD.

The best solution I can think of is to modify every instance the current tenant is injected into the code with a call to a method that resolves the tenant via claims. If the tenant is null in an area restricted with the [Authorize] attribute, it would imply the user is signed in via Azure AD, which would allow me to look at their claims. However, it really bothers me that I can't access the user's claims in the middleware, as I'm not sure what's really going on here.

---

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?
I have recently experienced the same and it is due to mutliple `Authentication Schemes`. `Authentication` and `Authorization` middlewares perform action only if `Default Scheme` is set in configuration. `The Security` actions are deferred to the `AuthorizeFilter` attribute otherwise.

Either make sure that you have `Default Authentication Scheme` set up or move the logic to newly created `IRourceFilter` (which I ended up doing by the way since I need to support multiple `Schemes`).

Please let me know, if my comment helps I can introduce a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access HttpContext from a custom component you are going to want to add `HttpContextAccessor` to your service collection as follows:

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

You can now resolve `HttpContext` as needed using dependency injection. This may or may not be helpful depending on how much control you have of the middleware that you are using.

For what it's worth, I've had little issue authenticating against AAD just using MSAL without additional third-party middleware. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! But I'm afraid this doesn't solve the problem... Not only does adding the HttpContextAccessor have no effect, but I believe [the multitenancy middleware adds the HttpContextAccessor for you](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/blob/master/src/SaasKit.Multitenancy/MultitenancyServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) in the call to AddMultitenancy(). I'm not sure where in the pipeline the user's authentication cookie is transformed into their claims when using Azure AD. It must be somewhere much further along than when using Identity.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be running on .NET Core 2.0 and running into this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318).